# Symfony2/Doctrine QueryBuilder multiple andwhere() fail

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

Bonjour,

I am having a problem with a simple request with QueryBuilder :

```
$query->where('ec.codeModePrelevement IN (:cbMode)')
        ->setParameter('cbMode', $modes)

        ->andWhere('ec.idStatusPaiement = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', EcheancesStatut::__EN_ATTENTE_PAIEMENT__)


        ->andWhere($query->expr()->eq('ec.idProduit',1))
         ->andWhere('ec.idProduit = :idProduit')
         ->setParameter('idProduit', 1 )
        ;
```

This return me no result as if in the database no user is corresponding  to this : user with status = 1 codeproduit = 1 and modePaiement = VM or VMMANO.
Ihave verified all possible mistakes of typo. And users corresponding in database do exist.

I have tried to remove id produit filter it "works" i have some result:

```
        $modes = array('VM','VMMANO');
        $query->where('ec.codeModePrelevement IN (:cbMode)')
        ->setParameter('cbMode', $modes)

        ->andWhere('ec.idStatusPaiement = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', EcheancesStatut::__EN_ATTENTE_PAIEMENT__)

         /*->andWhere('ec.idProduit = :idProduit')
         ->setParameter('idProduit', 1 )*/
        ;
```

This "works" to (removing modePaiement filter):

```
 $query/*->where('ec.codeModePrelevement IN (:cbMode)')
        ->setParameter('cbMode', $modes)*/

        ->where('ec.idStatusPaiement = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', EcheancesStatut::__EN_ATTENTE_PAIEMENT__)

         ->andWhere('ec.idProduit = :idProduit')
         ->setParameter('idProduit', 1 )
        ;
```

but this returns me no result to (removing status payment filter) :

```
$query->where('ec.codeModePrelevement IN (:cbMode)')
        ->setParameter('cbMode', $modes)

        /*->where('ec.idStatusPaiement = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', EcheancesStatut::__EN_ATTENTE_PAIEMENT__)*/

         ->andWhere('ec.idProduit = :idProduit')
         ->setParameter('idProduit', 1 )
        ;
```

Can you help me if you see something that i don't? Thank you.

Comment: Well, it simply looks like there is no result with codeModePrelevement in `$modes` **and** at the same time idProduit == 1. (Also you wrote "removing modePaiement filter", but you actually removed a filter on `codeModePrelevement`)

Comment: Yes but no, there are results for codeModePrelement in $mode and idProduit = 1. And modePaiement = codeModePrelevement i just wrote it differently but i mean codeModePrelement

Comment: Can you show the generated DQL/SQL code? (`$query->getDQL()` or `$query->getQuery()->getSQL()` respectively)

Comment: Check the sql executed in your symfony profiler, put where clauses one by one to identify which one restrict the database results

Comment: DQL = SELECT ec FROM BackendBundle\Entity\EcheancesClient ec WHERE ec.codeModePrelevement IN (:cbMode) AND ec.idStatusPaiement = :status AND ec.idProduit = :idProduit

Comment: SQL = SELECT (.....)  e0_.email AS email_10, e0_.code_devise AS code_devise_11, e0_.num_commande AS num_commande_12, e0_.taux_tva AS taux_tva_13, e0_.createdAt AS createdAt_14, e0_.dateResiliation AS dateResiliation_15 FROM echeances_client e0_ WHERE e0_.codeModePrelevement IN (?) AND e0_.idStatusPaiement = ? AND e0_.idProduit = ?

Comment: the couple idProduit = 1 /codeModePaiement = 1 return no result all others combinaison works and the query sql corresonding  => 

SELECT (...), e0_.numAbo AS numAbo_8, e0_.motifIncidentPaiement AS motifIncidentPaiement_9, e0_.email AS email_10, e0_.code_devise AS code_devise_11, e0_.num_commande AS num_commande_12, e0_.taux_tva AS taux_tva_13, e0_.createdAt AS createdAt_14, e0_.dateResiliation AS dateResiliation_15 FROM echeances_client e0_ WHERE e0_.codeModePrelevement IN ('VM', 'VMMANO') AND e0_.idProduit = 1;

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I have solved my problem. All was ggod it is my condition in my twig template that was false. Thank you.